# index match, excel ran out of resources

Tags: excel

I have tried several things to get rid of this error, I have no circular references, I deleted all names in name manager and I have tried to disable multi threading.

Anyone have any solutions for getting around `Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated.` ?

Here is my formula where I'm getting the issue, although i'm not sure if it is specific to this one formula that is causing this issue.

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Total'!B2:K36, MATCH(1,INDEX(('Control Manager'!$C$2= 'Total'!A:A) * (A32 = 'Total'!1:1),),0)),"-")`

Comment: Do you have to use the entire column (`Total!A:A`)? Same with the entire row reference.

Comment: No, well i tried adjusting A:A to A1:A100 and 1:1 to B1 to H1, seems to work.

Comment: Why not: `=INDEX('Total'!A:K,MATCH(Control Manager'!$C$2,'Total'!A:A,0),MATCH(A32,'Total'!1:1,0))` as a normal formula?

Comment: Thanks Scott, that seems to work better actually... Not sure why I had all the other stuff in there.

Comment: @ScottCraner why does your suggestion work better in terms of memory then mine? Is it a big difference?

Comment: it is a non array formula and as such can use full column references.  It may not make a noticeable difference on smaller datasets but will with larger datasets, in the time and resources.

Answer (score 2):

i had similar issue, was resolved by changing the worksheet name. earlier the worksheet had a hyphen (-) in its name, when renamed with an underscore (_), didnt get any more such errors.
However, i ve not checked by renaming the sheet again with an hyphen.